# All possible Kubernetes events with type

Tags: json, api, kubernetes, events, openshift

I want to react to certain Kubernetes/Openshift events,
therefor I need a list of all possible (Kubernetes) events with their type (normal vs. warning).

[Openshift event list (but without type info)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/events.html#events-reference)

Event data example:

```
   {
      "metadata": {
         ...
      },
      "involvedObject": {
         ...
      },
      "reason": "Created",
      "firstTimestamp": "...",
      "lastTimestamp": "...",
      "count": 1,
      "type": "Normal",
      "eventTime": null,
    }
```

Is there any relation between the type and the reason of the event?

How can I create/find such a comprehensive list (event reasons + type + involved object kind)?

Comment: Hello, could you please tell if you are looking specifically for Openshift events or Kubernetes events? From the Kubernetes perspective have you seen the [Kubernetes api: Event v1 core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#event-v1-core)? Also could you please tell more about the setup? Are your cluster self-managed or cloud-provider managed?

Comment: @DawidKruk I am looking for both Openshift and Kubernetes events (anything for the start). My goal is to have a comprehensive list of all events with reason and type.
My cluster is self-managed. I am developing an app, which handles kubernetes events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to give more of a baseline to the question than the actual solution. Feel free to expand it.

I haven't found the Kubernetes equivalent of the OpenShift documentation like used in the question:

- *[Docs.openshift.com: Container platform: 3.11: Dev guide: Events](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/events.html#events-reference)*

---

From Kubernetes perspective you can look on the source code of the components to see what events they can send.

`Kubelet` example:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Kubelets: Events: event.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/events/event.go)*

```golang
const (
    FailedToKillPod                = "FailedKillPod"
    FailedToCreatePodContainer     = "FailedCreatePodContainer"
    FailedToMakePodDataDirectories = "Failed"
    NetworkNotReady                = "NetworkNotReady"
)

const (
    CreatedContainer        = "Created"
    StartedContainer        = "Started"
    FailedToCreateContainer = "Failed"
    FailedToStartContainer  = "Failed"
    KillingContainer        = "Killing"
    PreemptContainer        = "Preempting"
    BackOffStartContainer   = "BackOff"
    ExceededGracePeriod     = "ExceededGracePeriod"
)
```

---

The relation between the type and a reason for an event could be described as:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Pkg: Apis: Core: types.go: Line 4670](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b11d0fbdd58394a62622787b38e98a620df82750/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L4670)*

```golang
// Valid values for event types (new types could be added in future)
const (
    // Information only and will not cause any problems
    EventTypeNormal string = "Normal"
    // These events are to warn that something might go wrong
    EventTypeWarning string = "Warning"
)
```

As you can see below the `Normal` type event was for the information that is not causing any issues. The `Warning` type event was created where there was an issue (trying to download not existent image: `fake`):

```sh
11s         Warning   Failed              pod/fake-f68cd66bc-hgxxv      Error: ErrImagePull
11s         Normal    BackOff             pod/fake-f68cd66bc-hgxxv      Back-off pulling image "fake"
11s         Warning   Failed              pod/fake-f68cd66bc-hgxxv      Error: ImagePullBackOff
14s         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/fake-f68cd66bc     Created pod: fake-f68cd66bc-hgxxv
14s         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/fake               Scaled up replica set fake-f68cd66bc to 1
50s         Normal    Scheduled           pod/nginx-6799fc88d8-ks76h    Successfully assigned default/nginx-6799fc88d8-ks76h to docker-desktop
```

To have a list of the events that happened in the cluster you could try to use dedicated application inside Kubernetes cluster to watch on the events and store them in a storage option of your choosing.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Cncf.io: Blog: 2020-12-10: The top Kubernetes APIs for cloud native observability:  Part 1: Kuberentes metrics service container apis 3](https://www.cncf.io/blog/2020/12/10/the-top-kubernetes-apis-for-cloud-native-observability-part-1-the-kubernetes-metrics-service-container-apis-3/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Generated: Kubernetes api: v1.20: Event v1 core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#event-v1-core)*